# Including image into html email using tinymce

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I am trying to add an image to a `tinymce` text area which is used to create an html email. All is working to an extent but I have a couple of queries:

When the image is selected I get 'blob' appearing at the beginning of the source, which I can't quite understand:

[image]

And if I continue then I see that the src tag loses the full path and remains as just the folder and filename only. This means that the recipients of the email can't view the image.

[image]

I have slightly adapted the example from 'tinymce' but not sure what to change to fix these two errors:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#email_text_area',
    plugins: [
        "advlist lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern" ],
    image_title: true, 
    automatic_uploads: true,
    images_upload_url: 'image_acceptor.php',
    file_picker_types: 'image', 
    file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

        input.onchange = function() {
            var file = this.files[0];
            var id = (new Date()).getTime();
            var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
            var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file);
            blobCache.add(blobInfo);
            cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
        };
        input.click();
    }
});
```

UPDATE:

It seemed that the image_acceptor.php needed to be changed to:

```
$filetowrite = "/home/..server-side public folder../email_images/" . $filename;
```

to write the image to the correct folder on the server and then change $filetowrite for the json response to the actual URL of the image:

```
$filetowrite = "https://.. url ../email_images/" . $filename;
```

This did not fix the 'blob' in the source dialog but did fix the image in the html source problem.

Comment: Blob stands for **Binary Large OBject**. its sth like raw image file, you are not expected to understand & use it.

Comment: A best practice about images in email is that *You'd better to avoid attaching images to the email itself, Instead save your image somewhere on publicly accessible web (e.g. your hosting) & put its address in `src` attribute of `<img>` residing in email.*

Comment: @BehradKhodayar Thanks, but that is what I am doing. The image is uploaded to the server and the <src> tag should be inserted into the html pointing to the image. The problem is that the full path is lost as shown in the image in the question. This means that the email is sent and the image shows as from email_images/image.png as opposed to https://host/.../email_images/image.png

Comment: You're welcome. I mean web address & not local. when any new image is uploaded to server, it may take an address like `/home/rgtiggiyhs/public_html/images/img01.jpg`. I suggest you to change it to web address like(e.g. `http://www.rgriffiths.com/images/img01.jpg`

Comment: You don't understand. The file HAS been uploaded to the server and that bit is working. But when I insert it using tinymce using the code above the <src> tag in the html text area loses the full path, and just shows the folder and file name. I need to know how to adjust the code above to insert the full path of the image, not just the folder and filename.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will need to configure [URL Handling](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/url-handling/):

try to add these lines:

```
tinymce.init({
    convert_urls: false,
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: false
});
```

defaults were all `true`.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the image the job of uploading the BLOB to the server is handled by your setting for `images_upload_url`

```
images_upload_url: 'image_acceptor.php'
```

What is the exact JSON that you are returning from that PHP script?  If you look in code view after you insert the image what is the src set to at that point?  Is it different after you save the content?

Comment: You are exactly right. The json response was just the folder/file and I changed the  image_acceptor.php file to sort this out. So all is working now, however I still get 'blob:https ..... ' with an odd filename as the source when I first select the image file. Once I have clicked OK and then go back to edit it the correct file path exists in the path, and most importantly it is also correct in the html source code. I guess I might just have to live with the initial source not viewing correctly, but I don't like it. See update for what worked for me.

Comment: "I still get 'blob:https ..... ' with an odd filename as the source when I first select the image file." - that is simply how the browser provides access to an image you select locally on your hard drive.